# Custom Cell init in 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' causing stacked cell to stack views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I create a cell using this func:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isFocusOn = [_userDefault boolForKey:@"mixFocusOn"];

    CDCChannelStrip *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (isFocusOn == TRUE) {
        NSNumber *setChan = [self.focusChannels objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSInteger chanInt = [setChan intValue];
        [cell initData:(chanInt)];
        [self getParameters:(setChan)];

    } else {
        NSInteger chanInt = indexPath.section;
        NSNumber *chanNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:chanInt]; // doesnt matter
        [cell initData:(chanInt)]; // init
        [self getParameters:(chanNum)]; // params
    }

    [self.mixMonitorView setChannelsStripToType:(cell)];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

The func in question is `initData` which looks like this:

```
- (void)initData:(NSInteger)channel {
        self.isBus = false;
        self.isSendChan = false;
        self.recallSafeFade = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recallSafe"]];
        self.recallSafeFade.y = 80;
        [self.recallSafeFade setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        self.recallSafeHead = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recallSafeHeadamp"]];
        [self.recallSafeHead setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        self.recallSafePan = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recallSafePan"]];
        self.recallSafePan.y = 768 - 141;
        [self.recallSafePan setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        self.channelNumber = channel;
        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
        _background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 122, 547)];
        [_background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"singleFader"]]];
        [self addSubview:_background];
        [self addChannelName];
        [self addInput];
        [self addPan];
        [self addOn];
        [self addMeter];
        [self addFader];
}
```

So the issue im having is, i need to call this func to setup my custom cell to look and function how i need it to. However, every time i call reload on the collectionview due to state changes, it layers the new views over the top of the old views (due to reocurring imageview alloc's)

So how can i apply this func to each cell automatically, yet not reapply it over the top every time i reload the cell?

Image of the issue ina  view debugger here:

[image]

Comment: It's because your are doing `addSubview:` each time in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and cells are reused. You have a custom cell `CDCChannelStrip`. Either add already the view inside it, that should always be there, or in `prepareForReuse`, remove them.

Comment: sorry i dont see any mention of addSubview in the cellForRowAt? or do you mean inside the initData func? can you expand your solution? I have to init the custom cell atleast once which means adding subviews? so it needs ot call somewhere and theres nowhere else to call it

Comment: `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is calling `initData:` which is calling `addSubView:`, that's more or less calling `addSubview:` in `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Cells are REUSED. So you can't do that like that. It will add each time new subview, that's why they are stacked.

Comment: right yeah i get it, but that has to be called some time otherwise its never set even for the initial reused cell... hence my question

Comment: Override `initWithFrame:` of your `CDCChannelStrip`, add there your views (maybe add constraints in case of the size of the cell may change), and use `@property` to keep references to theses view.

Comment: thats what im already doing with initData, its the same functions as initWithFrame as initWithFrame wasnt called by the collectionview delegate method correctly

Comment: I just created a UICollectionView and cells by code, and `initWithFrame:` of my custom Cell is called, as stated by the doc: `If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithFrame: method.`

Comment: my mistake, i was using a custom initWithChannel and passing in the channel strip number, so ill need to use initWithFrame and apply the channel number external to the init back in the cellforrowat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCell`s are reused. So, avoid doing `addSubView:` (directly or indirectly as in your case: `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is calling `initData:` which is calling `addSubView:`), each time in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

You are using a `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` only by code.
So there is no XIB/Storyboard were is the cell, and no `IBOutlet`.
According to the doc of `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, that's the part you fall into:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell
>   must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its
>   `initWithFrame:` method.

So, in *CDCChannelStrip.m*, override `initWithFrame:` and initialize its properties (that are "always" visible/used).

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _myImageViewProperty = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
        [self addSubview:_myImageViewProperty];
        etc.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateWithChannel:(NSInteger)channel
{
    self.channelNumber = channel;
    self.channelLabelName = @"Something";
    //etc.
}
```

You can also use `prepareForReuse` to "reinit" the cell as "virgin" (like it was just after `initWithFrame:` for instance.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.channelLabelName = @"";
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    //etc.
    [self.sometimesThatImageIsShown setHidden:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to create a separate xib for cell or prototype cell. Design you cell there and in cellForItemAtIndexPath you just manipulate your views and set values to your labels, images and other controllers.

Comment: the whole app is programatic there is no storyboard or custom xib stuff, is there no other approach I can take to keep inline with the apps design? I already have the class for my cell as it used ot be added as a UIView until i changed it to be reusable

Comment: In that case you need to check for eg. self.recallSafeFade is initialized then do not re initialze and add as subview, just perform whatever changes you need to perform. If it is un-initialized then initialize it and then only add it as subview

Comment: yeah this was my thought it just seemed like a messy approach to use so wanted to check what other options I had